# Not able to insert record in table

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am learning cordova and trying to create CRUD application. i am trying to insert record in my table CustomerOrder using below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("form").submit(function(event) {
  name = $("#name").val();
  mobile_number = $("#mobile_number").val();
  price = $("#price").val();
  address = $("#address").val();
    db.sqlBatch([
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CustomerOrder(name, mobile_number,price,address)',
    ['INSERT INTO CustomerOrder VALUES (name, mobile_number,price,address)', ['name', 'mobile_number','price','address'] ]
  ], function() {
    alert('Populated database OK');
  }, function(error) {
    alert('SQL batch ERROR: ' + error.message);
  });

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

But i am getting error as [image]

what could be the reason for this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a syntax issue in my insert into statement

it should be

```
  ['INSERT INTO CustomerOrder (name, mobile_number,price,address) VALUES (?, ?,?,?)', [name, mobile_number,price,address] ]
```